# cmake to link to dll without lib

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, linker

I've been given a dll without libs.
The dll comes with hpp and h files.
I used dumpbin to create an exports.def file and lib to create a library.

I'm using the following CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 3.22 )

project ( mytest )

include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libincludedir")

add_executable ( mytest main.cpp)

target_link_libraries ( mytest LINK_PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libincludedir/anewlib.lib  )
```

The original dll and created lib and h and hpp files are all in the libincludedir. Dll is also copied to the bin dir where the exe would be.

I get no linker errors with the lib, but no functions defined in the include headers have bodies found. Types are Undefined. Classes are incomplete.

How do I fix this? Can I progress with what I was given or should I ask for more?

Comment: Run `cmake --version`. Unless it reads `2.8.11`, you should not put `2.8.11` in `cmake_minimum_required`.

Comment: thats not really gonna do anything for my problem right?

Comment: No, but it will _cause you problems_ down the line when you hit up against one of the roughly 100 vexing behaviors that have been fixed by CMake's policy system. CMake will soon drop compatibility with versions below 2.8.12, so you're really setting yourself up for failure here.

Comment: haha fair enough

Comment: Are you having compile errors or link errors?  Incomplete types would normally cause compile errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you created the `.lib` correctly, this is how you would set up something linkable:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(example)

add_library(anewlib::anewlib SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
  anewlib::anewlib
  PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libincludedir/anewlib.lib"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libincludedir/anewlib.dll"
  IMPORTED_NO_SONAME "TRUE"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libincludedir"
)

add_executable(mytest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mytest PRIVATE anewlib::anewlib)
```

*Always* link to targets since they provide CMake with much more information than a raw library file. Here, we're telling CMake about the locations of both the `.lib` and the `.dll`, that it doesn't have a SONAME (a *nix only thing, anyway, but good to include), and the include path that linkees should use to find its associated headers.

Then when you link `mytest` to it, `mytest` will have a correct link line constructed and it will see the right headers.

Comment: It didn't work. The forward declared class I need to use in the include header is still incomplete. This might be a silly question but how does an import lib allow for compile time understanding of a forward declared class like this?

Comment: additional question, what does the :: do? scoping? why is it needed?

Comment: The `::` ensures that CMake treats the name as a target, rather than as a system library. Imported targets should _always_ have `::` in the name and I even advocate for creating aliases to normal targets containing a `::`.

Comment: Regarding "incomplete" types... you won't be able to use them, except as pointers. You will have to contact your vendor to determine how they intend for you to use those types. It is not uncommon in C APIs to have opaque structs given as incomplete types. You must use the library functions to create, manipulate, and later destroy them.